# Creating a loop for allowTimes for the plugin datetimepicker (instead of hardcoding each quarters)

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, plugins, properties

I'm trying to ethical hack the plugin datetimepicker in order to dynamically create a loop to display each quarter of every hour instead of hard coding them. My goal is, instead of typing for example:

```
jQuery("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
        scrollMonth : false,
        allowTimes: ['07:00','07:15','07:30','07:45','08:00','08:15','08:30','08:45','09:00','09:15','09:30','09:45','10:00','10:15','10:30','10:45','11:00','11:15','11:30','11:45','12:00','12:15','12:30','12:45','13:00','13:15','13:30','13:45','14:00','14:15','14:30','14:45','15:00','15:15','15:30','15:45','16:00','16:15','16:30','16:45','17:00','17:15','17:30','17:45'],
        formatTime: 'g:i a',
        minDate:'+1970/01/04'
    });
```

using this loop:

```
var append = "[";

    for (var xh=7; xh<=17; xh++) {
        for (var xm=0; xm<60; xm+=15) { 
            append += "'"+("0"+xh).slice(-2)+':'+("0"+xm).slice(-2)+"',";
        }
    }
    append += "]";
    append.slice(-1,1);
    console.log(append);
```

Which will output the same result of my first example (allowTimes: ['07:00','07:15','07:30','07:45','08:00' and so on]) but for some reason, it's not working.

Does anyone know why?

Is in not possible to add an array (allowTimes:append) to fire a jquery property of a plugin?
And if is not, why it's not working my code which is outputting the same result of my first example that is actually working?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are trying to build is not a String but an Array of Strings.

Therefore :

```
var times = []; // empty Array

for (var xh=7; xh<=17; xh++) {
    for (var xm=0; xm<60; xm+=15) { 
        times.push(("0" + xh).slice(-2) + ':' + ("0" + xm).slice(-2)); // push a time String onto the Array
    }
}
console.log(times);
```

Comment: Great solution!!